# Verilog HDL syntax error near text "for"; expecting "endmodule"

Tags: verilog

I was implementing a basic binary adder in Verilog.  From my limited understanding, the following should add two 16-bit values:

```
module ADD(X, Y, Z);
input[15:0] X;
input[15:0] Y;

output Z[15:0];
wire C[15:0];

assign C[0] = 0;
integer i;
for(i=1; i<16; i=i+1) begin 
   assign C[i]=(X[i-1]&Y[i-1])|(X[i-1]&C[i-1])|(Y[i-1]&C[i-1]);
end
for(i=0; i<16; i=i+1) begin
   assign Z[i]=X[i]^Y[i]^C[i];
end
endmodule
```

However, I get an error when I try to synthesize the above.

> Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at add.v(10) near text "for";
> expecting "endmodule"

I'm not sure what is wrong with the code.

Comment: You could skip the for loop with: `output [15:0] Z; wire [15:0] C = { (X&Y)|(X&C)|(Y&C) , 1'b0}; assign Z=X^Y^C;`. If you don't need to demonstrate the full adder operations, then just say `assign Z=X+Y;`

Comment: I tried doing C = { (X&Y)|(X&C)|(Y&C) } and I got an error saying that I have to assign individually to array elements.

Comment: I guessing C is still declared as `wire C [15:0]`, should be `wire [15:0] C`. They have different meanings. Working example [here]( http://www.edaplayground.com/x/U8) (ModelSim10.1d/Icarus0.10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The for-loop is used outside of an always block, so `i` needs to be a `genvar` instead of an `integer`. Also, you probably want Z and C to declared an packed arrays instead of unpacked, mo the `[15:0]` to the other side.

```
output [15:0] Z; // make as packed bits
wire [15:0] C;

assign C[0] = 0;
genvar i; // not integer
generate // Required for IEEE 1364-2001, optional for *-2005 and SystemVerilog
for(i=1; i<16; i=i+1) begin 
  assign C[i]=(X[i-1]&Y[i-1])|(X[i-1]&C[i-1])|(Y[i-1]&C[i-1]);
end
for(i=0; i<16; i=i+1) begin
  assign Z[i]=X[i]^Y[i]^C[i];
end
endgenerate // must be matched with a generate
```

Alternative solution 1: use an always block

```
output reg[15:0] Z; // make as reg
reg [15:0] C;

integer i; // integer OK
always @* begin
  for(i=1; i<16; i=i+1) begin
    if (i==0)  C[i] = 1'b0;
    else       C[i]=(X[i-1]&Y[i-1])|(X[i-1]&C[i-1])|(Y[i-1]&C[i-1]);
    Z[i]=X[i]^Y[i]^C[i];
  end
end
```

Alternative solution 2: bit-wise assignment

```
output [15:0] Z;

wire [15:0] C = { (X&Y)|(X&C)|(Y&C) , 1'b0 };
assign Z = X^Y^C;
```

Alternative solution 3: behavioral assignment

```
output [15:0] Z;
assign Z = X+Y;
```

Working examples [here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/U8)

Comment: All the alternative solutions work, but the first solution still gives me the same error.
I am using Quartus II 13.1

Comment: @Harry, I did a little digging; Veilog-2001 requires a `generate`/`endgeneate` wrapper. It is optional for Verilog-2005 and SystemVerilog. Quartus support Verilog-2001, not Verilog-2005. Quartus does support SystemVerilog when the file ends in `.sv` instead of `.v`. For the first solution to work, either add  `generate`/`endgeneate` (see updated answer) or enable SystemVerilog by renaming the file .

Answer (score 1):

Change the definition of `i` from `integer` to `genvar`.

Notice that `for` loops can be used either in an `always` block or in a `generate` block. The latter is implicitly the context that you are using it in your code. In generate blocks, the loop variable should be of type `genvar`.

More info in [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf)

Comment: I replaced the integer in the above code with genvar and still get the same error.

Comment: @Harry, what simulator are you using?